# JOINing two mapping tables

Tags: mysql, join, query, group-by, mariadb-10.5

I have two mapping tables as

```
CREATE TABLE ProjectDevelopers
(
DeveloperID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
ProjectID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
INDEX(ProjectID),
PRIMARY KEY(DeveloperID,ProjectID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE SimilarProjects
(
ProjectID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
SimilarProjectID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
INDEX(SimilarProjectID),
PRIMARY KEY(ProjectID,SimilarProjectID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

For each developer in `SimilarProjects` table, I `COUNT` similar projects where the developer is the developer of `ProjectID` too,

```
SELECT  a.DeveloperID,COUNT(*)
    FROM  ProjectDevelopers a
    JOIN  SimilarProjects b  ON a.ProjectID=b.SimilarProjectID
    JOIN  ProjectDevelopers c  ON b.ProjectID=c.ProjectID
                              AND a.DeveloperID=c.DeveloperID
    GROUP BY  a.DeveloperID
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO ProjectDevelopers (DeveloperID,ProjectID) values
(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (1,2), (2,3), (5,4), (6,5)

INSERT INTO SimilarProjects (ProjectID,SimilarProjectID) values
(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5)
```

In the above query, for `DeveloperID` 1, I count `SimilarProjectID` 2 because he is the developer of `ProjectID` 2.

In the next step, I need to `COUNT` similar projects where the developer or any of his collaborators was the developer.

In the sample data, I need to count `SimilarProjectID` 2 and 3 because `DeveloperID` 2 is a collaborator of `DeveloperID` 1 in `ProjectID` 1.

Comment: If 1 is similar to 2, is 2 not similar to 1?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille no, the reference is only table `SimilarProjects`. We consider only projects named a similar project. It is not reciprocal.

Comment: I'm quite sure that even in US English, similarity is reciprocal.  Your next step can be solved with the criterium "IN" and a sub-select.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille similarity is reciprocal, but we look for linked similarity. Sure, a sub-query of `SELECT`ing collaborators for each `DeveloperID` can solve the problem; but how to implement it with reasonable performance.

Comment: I'm not particularly good at tuning slow queries, but my understanding is that, when you are putting together words like "reasonable" and "performance", you really need to be more specific.  Different people may have different ideas of what reasonable performance is.